# Use an Ironpython script to filter and pass filter selections between tables

Tags: filter, ironpython, spotfire

I have two tables in the analysis. I am using the script below to be able to filter table A and pass those filter selections to the matching filter in table B. Table A and B are visualized in a bar chart. I am triggering the code when the value of a document property changes, following instructions [here](https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-45663).

I am running into two problems.

1) After the script runs, clicking Reset All Filters results in only table A being displayed in the visualization. Clicking Reset All Filters again fixes the issue.

2)When I add a second filter (commented out in the code below), making a selection in the Type_A or or Type_B filter wipes out the type B data from the visualization. I think the problem is in how IncludeAllValues is being handled, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
from System import Guid

#Get the active page and filterPanel
page = Application.Document.ActivePageReference
filterPanel = page.FilterPanel

theFilterA = filterPanel.TableGroups[0].GetFilter("Type_A")
lbFilterA = theFilterA.FilterReference.As[ListBoxFilter]()

theFilter2A = filterPanel.TableGroups[1].GetFilter("Type_A")
lb2FilterA = theFilter2A.FilterReference.As[ListBoxFilter]()
lb2FilterA.IncludeAllValues = False
lb2FilterA.SetSelection(lbFilterA.SelectedValues)


#########################Type_B###########################
# theFilterB = filterPanel.TableGroups[0].GetFilter("Type_B")
# lbFilterB = theFilterB.FilterReference.As[ListBoxFilter]()

# theFilter2B = filterPanel.TableGroups[1].GetFilter("Type_B")
# lb2FilterB = theFilter2B.FilterReference.As[ListBoxFilter]()
# lb2FilterB.IncludeAllValues = False
# lb2FilterB.SetSelection(lbFilterB.SelectedValues)
```